# How to start a web browser in a given session?

Tags: terminal, browser, curl, cookies

I got a session cookie but I don't see any easy way to open a web browser with it from the terminal.

Context: I got a script with few cURL commands. After running it I got a prepered user session that I would like to continue working with in the web browser.

How to achieve my goal?
Browser extension? JS script? Rest server with redirection endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to create a test-only website that orchestrates the log-in and state injection.

From a website, you can easily manipulate with the cookies and even add some useful debugging tools.

In my project, this new endpoint became a part of the tested project under a flag that disables it in the production environment.